# How to import multiple matlab files into R (Using package R.Matlab)

Tags: r, matlab, import, get, paste

Thank you in advance for your're help. I am using R to analyse some data that is initially created in Matlab. I am using the package "R.Matlab" and it is fantastic for 1 file, but I am struggling to import multiple files.

The working script for a single file is as follows...

```
install.packages("R.matlab")

library(R.matlab)

x<-("folder_of_files")
path <- system.file("/home/ashley/Desktop/Save/2D Stream", package="R.matlab")
pathname <- file.path(x, "Test0000.mat")
data1 <- readMat(pathname)
```

And this works fantastic. The format of my files is 'Name_0000.mat' where between files the name is a constant and the 4 digits increase, but not necesserally by 1.

My attempt to load multiple files at once was along these lines...

```
for (i in 1:length(temp)) 
  data1<-list()
     {data1[[i]] <- readMat((get(paste(temp[i]))))}
```

And also in multiple other ways that included and excluded path and pathname from the loop, all of which give me the same error:

```
Error in get(paste(temp[i])) : 
  object 'Test0825.mat' not found
```

Where 0825 is my final file name. If you change the length of the loop it is always just the name of the final one.

I think the issue is that when it pastes the name it looks for that object, which as of yet does not exist so I need to have the pasted text in speach marks, yet I dont know how to do that.

Sorry this was such a long post....Many thanks

Comment: If `temp` is actually a list of your files (e.g. `temp <- list.files(pattern='.mat')` ), then `data1 <- lapply(temp, function(pathname) readMat(pathname))` or simply `data1 <- lapply(temp, readMat)` should work.

Comment: That second option worked a treat thank you! First one, not so much. And yes I forgot to include that, but temp was my file list, cheers for working that out